# Java-client to call algorithm in jar-file which is part of a web-interface in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an application written in Java (Netbeans 8.0, JDK 1.7) where an algorithm performs technical calculations. The algorithm is packed into a jar-file, and I use it currently in two ways:

1. I access the algorithm-containing jar-file via its public methods from a local Java program, where the jar-file is in that program's library path.
2. I built a web-interface for this jar-file by employing Spring MVC (Spring Framework 3.2.7). The resulting war-file (containing the algorithm-containing jar-file) is now sitting on a server (Glassfish 4), and one can call the algorithm via the webbrowser.

Both works fine. Now I want to access this algorithm-containing jar-file which is in the war-file on the server also by employing my local Java client. I spent quite some time on this but I have big difficulties to get started.

I had the impression that I cannot directly call the jar-file's public methods over the network. Is this correct?

I was thinking about extending the Spring MVC somehow like adding a dedicated servlet which handles the communication between my local Java client and the algorithm-containing jar-file.

Is this possible at all? Does it make sense? If yes, can someone point me to an example how this can be done? Like, where to put the required classes?

Comment: why don't you use docker instead? you could create an image with your jar and access it trough internet

Comment: You can call your web-method from local Java program, for example by using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html)

Comment: @Blazerg: I thought about some minor changes in the existing code, which I would try first. But thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ Nikolay Shevchenko: Thank you very much for this hint. I am now looking into this and I think this might solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> had the impression that I cannot directly call the jar-file's public methods over the network. Is this correct?

I  suggest you take a look at RPC: "a remote procedure call (RPC) is when a computer program causes a procedure (subroutine) to execute in a different address space (commonly on another computer on a shared network), which is coded as if it was a normal (local) procedure call, without the programmer explicitly coding the details for the remote interaction. That is, the programmer writes essentially the same code whether the subroutine is local to the executing program, or remote." [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)

Comment: @ anthony yaghi: I looked into this already but was wondering how exactly to implement this in th eexisting Spring Framework based solution without oo many changes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could make it work, at least on the local server:

In the controller class of the Web-based GUI, I add a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xx0/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getCalculationResults (
            @RequestParam String id, @RequestParam double e1, @RequestParam double e2
    ) {
    System.out.println("getCalculationResults(): Input ... id="+id+"   e1="+e1+"   e2="+e2); 
    // here we can pass the parameters e1 and e2 to the algorithm 
    // (implemented in the jar-file, which is in the library when creating the war-file)

    // we get results e.g. as x1, x2, x3, and send them back in some format
    return new String("x1, x2, x3"); 
}
```

The Java-client, e.g. a stand-alone program, can now call the jar-file, which is part of the war-file on the server with code like this:

```
public class AlgoCallerForTesting {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    AlgoCallerForTesting algoCaller= new AlgoCallerForTesting(); 
    algoCaller.processRequestToServiceTest(); 
}

private void processRequestToServiceTest () {
    String strId= "userXYZ"; 
    double e1=12.34, e2=56.7; 
    String request= "http://localhost:8080/AlgoGUI/" + "xx0/?id="+strId+"&e1="+e1+"&e2="+e2; 
    String erg=""; 
    try {
        URL url = new URL(request);
        BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
        String txt=""; 
        while ((txt=dis.readLine()) != null) erg += txt; 
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    System.out.println(erg);
}

}
```